# Will I get a job in aerospace field after graduating from M.Sc in astronomy and B.Tech in aerospace engineering?

Tags: astrophysics

I am a student of class 12. I am fascinated about space and rockets. I want to be an astronomer and I know that I have to get a B.Sc, then M.Sc, and then Ph.D in astronomy. I came to know that there are less opportunities for research in astronomy, since many organizations like ISRO not only employ scientists, but also employ engineers to make satellites and spacecrafts. Can I get a job in aerospace field after doing my M.Sc in astronomy?

Comment: It depends on you; it's a common combination.

Comment: What exactly does "depends on you" mean?

Comment: Asking questions that use the clauses "Will I .." or "Can I .." give the impression that you are seeking some form of guaranteed or assured outcome. The only certain outcome for all of is that one day we will all die. What happens between now & then depends on circumstances. Rephrasing the question with clauses such as, "would it be possible ...", or "could ..." gives the impression you are asking about possibilities of particular event occurring.

Comment: Ok sir, so would it be possible????

Comment: I don't think that this is the right place to post this question.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because this question is not about astronomy as defined in the help center.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generally: yes, that is possible. There are many people living with such career path.

The main factor on how likely that is to work out is on you, your interests, on what projects you undertake, on your engagement there.

Astronomy and space engineering are not separate fields (if you look closely enough, you find an overlap between any two fields of your choice). Space engineering and astronomy have many projects which are undertaken jointly by people from both fields - and need to be done that way. That is especially true when it comes to the instrumentation part for satellite missions. Even as an observing astronomer you will possibly have to deal with the intricacies of your instruments or orbital mechanics or thermal intertia and control.

Also think a bit out of the stereotype box: astrophysics is way more than observational astronomy where you analyse images taken by a telescope or two. A large part is modelling different physical processes - a skill applicable and transferrable to other areas easily. There is laboratory astrophysics with close links to material sciences and chemistry and geology and petrology. There's plasma and particle physics when it comes to interplanetary probes and their instruments. Close ties to geophysics in knowledge and technology when it comes to surface investigations on other planets.

The important point is: you will (need to) learn to learn. That is one of the main points of a university degree. And that will enable you to switch to related fields, these opportunities will open themselves when you follow with your carreer your interests.

Comment: Thanks, A lot!!